# Existence of a limit cycle for this system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Does this system have a limit cycle?
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=\frac{x^3+x+\cos(y)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2(xy)}}\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=\frac{y^3+\sin(x)}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2(xy)}}
\end{align}

I've tried polar coordinates, Lyapunov function, and Bendixson theorem, but I haven't been able to find an answer yet. Thank you!

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Do you have any reason to believe that there's a limit cycle? Because it surely doesn't look that way if you plot the [phase portrait](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot+%7Bx%5E3%2Bx%2Bcos%28y%29%2C+y%5E3%2Bsin%28x%29%7D) (you can forget about those square root factors, they don't affect the phase portrait since they only amount to a rescaling of time).

Comment: @HansLundmark Yeah I thought so too, but I wasn't so sure so I asked here. How could I prove that there isn't one without plotting the phase portrait though?

Comment: I think if you sketch the phase portrait by hand, just by determining the nullclines and checking how the vector field is pointing in the different sectors of the plane, it should become quite obvious.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you!